# Display session parameters with twig

Tags: session, twig

I would like to display all session variables with twig but I dont know exactly how:

```
{% for variable in app.session %}
    session[ {{variable clef}}] = {{variable value}}
{% endfor %}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this, it will work for other associative arrays as well:

```
{% for key, value in app.session %}
    session['{{ key }}'] = {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's also explained in the documentation: [Iterating over Keys and Values](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use twig's debugging function, `dump`. This will work even if the `value` of a `key` is an object or array.

```
{{ dump(app.session.all) }}
```